# How to pass variables from controller to show their values in blade file

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I want to show variables value in blade file. Below is the controller code:-

```
public function ClientListReviews()
{
    // to show client list get data from users booking table

      $select_clientlist = 
      DB::table('users_booking')>where('service_provider', '=', 1)->get();

      if(count($select_clientlist) > 0)
      {
         return view('client-database')->with($select_clientlist);
      }
      else
      {
         return view('client-database')->withMessage('No Details Found');
      }
 }
```

I want to show the values coming in $select_clientlist variable. Below is the code in my blade file:-

```
@foreach($select_clientlist as $clientlist)

  {{$clientlist->firstname}}
@endforeach
```

And below is the route file code:-

```
Route::post('client_list_ajax','ClientDatabase\ClientdatabaseController@ClientListReviews');
```

I am receiving error.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error could be here   `$select_clientlist = 
      DB::table('users_booking')>where('service_provider', '=', 1)->get();` ... because `$select_clientlist` is NOT defined !!!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable using compact method

```
 return View::make('myviewfolder.myview', compact('view1','view2','view3'));
```

view1,view2,view3 are variable names

Comment: $select_clientlist is  undefined when count is zero.try to pass empty array when count is zero

Comment: orelse check if (isset($select_clientlist)) in your view file

Answer (score 0):

Either use as

```
return view('client-database')->with('select_clientlist',$select_clientlist);
```

Or

```
return view('client-database',compact('select_clientlist'));
```

Also add in `select_clientlist` else part to prevent undefined error

```
public function ClientListReviews()
{
    // to show client list get data from users booking table

      $select_clientlist = 
      DB::table('users_booking')>where('service_provider', '=', 1)->get();

      if(count($select_clientlist) > 0)
      {
         return view('client-database')->with('select_clientlist',$select_clientlist);
      }
      else
      {
         $select_clientlist = [];
         return view('client-database')->with('select_clientlist',$select_clientlist)->withMessage('No Details Found');
      }
 }
```

OR check by `isset($select_clientlist)` in blade file

```
$__currentLoopData = isset($select_clientlist)?$select_clientlist:[];
```

Comment: I have tried both these methods, not working. Still same error

Comment: @TS.developer : add blank `$select_clientlist` in else part so that not error for `$select_clientlist`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only pass the variable when there is records wrap your for each inside isset

```
if (isset($select_clientlist)) {
   foreach($select_clientlist as $clientlist) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `query` should be like this . you may be forget `SELECT` statement

```
$select_clientlist = DB::table('users_booking')->select('*')->where('service_provider', '=', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass that variable to your view either way .. it should be a collection. If there are no records, it is just empty. The `foreach` wont run if its empty. Its as simple as that. No need to check if anything is set or is empty etc... just always pass that collection.

```
public function ClientListReviews()
{
    $select_clientlist = DB::table('users_booking')->where('service_provider', 1)->get();

    $view = view('client-database', compact('select_clientlist'));

    if ($select_clientlist->isEmpty()) {
        $view->with('message', 'No Details Found');
    }

    return $view;
}
```